# How can i change webBrowser content asynchronously?

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, webbrowser-control

I'm doing a Rss Feed Reader program, and i wanted to display articles descriptions in html format.I search few articles and questions about it,i find extendedrichTextbox and somethings like that but i don't like them.(because its too complicated,i just wanted to display value) So i decide to display contents in webbrowser.And i save all articles description html codes into seperate html files,then when i want to display content in webbrowser i receive file path and set it as Webbrowser.Url

here is my code:

```
 var articles = user.RssFeeds.Where(r => r.Id == rssFeedId).Select(p =>     p.Articles).First();
 var filePath = (from a in articles
                where a.Title == articleName
                select a.FilePath).First();
webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(filePath);
```

My problem is when setting Webbrowser.Url it needs too much time,and my Window freeze 5-10 seconds.When it happends i try this:

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(filePath));
```

But it's not work because it still work on same thread,i tried sum other stupid ways but they didn't work either.This problem happens when i click first article node in treeview,after that all articles displaying without freezing.

So I wait your answers and suggestions.Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: hi dear Selman Genç, is there any possibity to be in touch with you. Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `WebBrowser.Url` only triggers the download, normally you also need to handle `DocumentComplete` event before moving to the next URL. You can do so using an asynchronous loop, like `DoWorkAsync` [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19718530/1768303).

Comment: Thanks,but i solve this problem with using webBrowser.DocumentStream,however if i need async. work again i will use your code,thank you anyway :)

Comment: @Selman22, `webBrowser.DocumentStream` is async too, same as `webBrowser.DocumentText`. It is not guaranteed to complete synchronously, even if it does sometimes.